# How to properly constrain a React state variable based on another one?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const nums: string[] = [...];

const [left, setLeft] = useState(0);
const [right, setRight] = useState(1);
useEffect(() => { if (right < left) setRight(left); }, [left]);
useEffect(() => { if (left > right) setLeft(right); }, [right]);

// this throws if right < left:
const slice = nums.slice(left, right);
const sum = slice.reduce((s, c) => s + c);
return <p>Sum: {sum}</p>;
```

If `right` is changed to something smaller than `left`, this code will crash on the next render, despite the constraint applied in the effect, because:

- the effect runs after the faulty render
- even if it ran immediately, `setRight` only changes the value of `right` in the next render

I can think of various ways to avoid or work around this, but what would you say is the proper/idiomatic way to do something like this?

Comment: Can you provide more of your code ?

Comment: @OneQ this is my code. It's a general question about a construct I commonly encounter. What more would you like to know?

Comment: Define why code will crash on next render.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I don't really see what value that would add to the question, but alright, I'll make that concrete

Answer (score 3):

Setting state in an effect is usually a code smell. You need to either:

- Constrain it in the handler that sets this to a "bad" value in the first place, before it even gets set.
- Or allow it to be set to a "bad" value and just clamp them in render, and only ever use that value to read from.

```
const [left, setLeft] = useState(0);
const [right, setRight] = useState(1);

// ...

const clampedLeft = Math.min(left, right)
const clampedRight = Math.max(0, left)
```

Comment: Which of the 2 would you say is more idiomatic or, if you can't answer that, which would you personally prefer?

Comment: It depends on the use case. For example, if this is user inputted data, you might let it enter them incorrectly, still displaying the incorrect number in the field (and so storing the value "incorrectly") and show an error. The second way might be better then. But also, you probably would only copy the form state into the real state when its valid in the first place...I'd aim for the first option personally.

Comment: It may also depend on what you want to happen when the values change further. So for example, if right dips below left, it gets clamped in both cases. But if left later gets lowered, should right lower with it down to its "real" value? If so, option 2 will model that, but option 1 means the clamped value is the real value, so right won't lower unless explicitly told to

Comment: @NicholasTower an important distinction indeed. I also just realized the need for an option 3: say you want the behaviour of option 2 (right keeps its preferred value), but the code that sets `left` is outside of your control, e.g. it's a prop instead of state. How would you handle that? A possibility I see is to combine clamping for the first render and a state-setting effect to make it "permanent".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the effect hook at all for this.

```
const slice = nums.slice(left, right < left ? left : right);
```

---

Your edit doesn't make any sense. Rather, it will raise XY problem. Why are you so over complicating the scenario?

Just slice the nums based on the left and right value defining a condition. And then, the handler for updating left and right will do the work. Whenever the left and right value changes the code will work for you on the next render (after updating the left/right values). So, just keep it simple.

```
const slice = nums.slice(left, Math.min(left, right))
```

Comment: The edit inviting people to treat it as an XY problem is exactly why I was hesitant to add such details. You can just trust that there is some code which trips if left > right and that it's not practical - whether desired or not - to change that bit.

Answer (score 1):

Since both states are dependent on each other, I would use a reducer to contain the logic for both an constrain the actual state values:

```
const reducer = ({ left, right }, { l = left, r = right }) => ({
  left: Math.min(l, r)
  right: Math.max(l, r)
})

// init
const [{ left, right }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { left: 0, right: 1 });

// update
const updateLeft = l => dispatch({ l })
const updateRight = r => dispatch({ r })
```

In addition, the problem is not with the `Array.slice()` method, which would return an empty array, if left is greater than right, but with the `Array.reduce()`, which throws an error when the array is empty, and there's no initial value. A simple solution is to add an initial value:

```
const sum = slice.reduce((s, c) => s + c, 0); // <- 0 initial value
```

Comment: You're right that they are dependent on each other, I've edited the question to reflect that and not cause any confusion around that. Thanks